# Eliminate hardcoding of connection string

Tags: c++, connection-string, ado

I have made GUI that can perform usual operations with the database ( load existing data, modify it or add new entries). GUI is made in `C++` using raw `WinAPI`.

The problem is in connection string. It is hardcoded so it forces the user to keep the database in the same folder where the GUI is. Below is the example in `C++`, using `ADO`:

```
static wchar_t *bstrConnect= L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;\
                                 Data Source = .\\MyDatabase.accdb";
```

I wish to allow user to have freedom of choice when it comes to where database will be located but I do not know how to modify the application/connection string to do this.

I have tried to search here for examples, and have searched online but had no success. Perhaps me being a beginner and self-taught has something to do with that.

### QUESTION:

Is there an example/tutorial/documentation that can show me the correct principle for handling this type of "scenario"?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to replace `.\\MyDatabase.accdb` part of your connection string with the full path to that database file. Currently it is a relative path.

In other words, you need to build the connection string at run-time using available string formatting/concatenation functions.

Comment: I have done that, the example is from an old test of mine. Still, the point is to find the path of the database file before my application runs, so I can configure properly the connection string...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff "before my application runs..." That in itself means it is a setup issue, not an application issue. Your question is unclear. Do you want to know how to build a dynamic string? How to allow the user to specify a command-line-argument which you'll use to build said-sting? How to manage  configuration data between run-times? Please update your question with more precise requirements and *exact* expected behaviors.

Comment: @WhozCraig: *Please update your question...* I am in a huge mess at the moment, I will edit the post in such a way that no confusion will remain after I get spare time...

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is as previously suggested by *wallyk*, save it to a configuration file of some sort, then read when required.

For example, the simplest method could be to have a standard .INI file that contains the following:

```
[Database]
File=".\MyDatabase.accdb"
```

This kind of files can be trivially used with the WinApi functions [WritePrivateProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetPrivateProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx).

Of course it can be any type of file, as simple or complex as you need it. Or you can even save those bits of data in the registry if you really want to. Another question would be where to save it, and that can be another whole discussion (lots of questions here already tackle on that point). The idea is, in short, to have it stored somewhere that can be read at runtime instead of hardcoded.

In terms of code, that would means, in every place when the program requires a connection string, instead of reading a hardcoded constant you'll call a function that will return it. The function in turn will build it (encapsulating all logic to get it from a configuration file), doing something like this:

1. Read the configuration file using [GetPrivateProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx) (or appropriate functions/libraries if using something else).
2. On failure of that the system might fall back to a default file or just throw an error and report to the user.
3. Concatenate it with a hardcoded *provider* parameter, or choose it among a list of possible choices (I would hardcode as you often will use a fixed DB engine, and different engines need different connection parameters, and storing the whole string in the file is unnecessary if you know how to build it in my opinion, so let's not open another failure possible point).
4. Build the final string from both pieces of data. Additional parameters can be included here too, either read from configuration or hardcoded or received as function parameters, as appropriate for each case.

Comment: Depending on your needs, if you haven't got a setting (or the file it specifies doesn't exist) you might want to show a standard "File Open" dialog and let the user choose the file (which would then be written to the configuration setting for next time).

Comment: @TripeHound Sure, forgot that possibility, it's a good option too, depending on the use case. The hypothetical function I'm mentioning could ask the user for a file and save the result back as well, it's a good addition.

Answer (score 0):

Your application doesn't have to use hardcoding.  Devise a configuration strategy and implement it.

For example, look for one in the current user's home directory, user's configuration subdirectory, user's group configuration directory, system configuration directory, and/or display a list of default configurations.